# How to fetch first element from a stream of JSON objects?

Tags: json, jq

Example

```
{
  "name": "bar",
  "thing": true,
  "new_key": 0
}
{
  "name": "baz",
  "thing": false,
  "new_key": 0
}
```

If I run `.name` I get output as

```
bar
baz
```

I want only `bar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`first/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#first(expr),last(expr),nth(n;expr)) in conjunction with **-n**/**--null-input** flag.

```
jq -n 'first(inputs.name)'
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-MPl4kHmpw)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There's also [`input`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#input) (whithout "s") which in combination with the `--null-input` (or `-n`) flag emits just the first item:

```bash
jq -n 'input.name'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NRky2LR2PXE)